# Binding command to button in silverlight 4 using mvvm

Tags: mvvm, binding, button, silverlight-4.0, icommand

I have a user control called `HomePage.xaml`. I'm creating a model instance (using MVVM pattern) in the code behind file in the constructor of page as

```
MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
```

I have a button in `HomePage.xaml` which I want to bind to the command inside `MainViewModel` called `GetData()` and want to populate the data in datagrid. `MainViewModel` has an `ObservableCollection` which I would use to bind the data in datagrid.

Populating the data in datagrid without binding command works fine.

I'm binding the button as:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stkPanelInput" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<Button x:Name="buttonGetData" Width="70" Content="GetData" Command="{Binding GetData}"  Click="buttonGetData_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How shall I bind the command using MVVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Archie said, set the DataContext of your page to the instance of your MainViewModel.

```
DataContext = model;
```

Then you have your XAML look like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stkPanelInput" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<Button x:Name="buttonGetData" Width="70" Content="GetData" Command="{Binding GetDataCommand}"  Click="buttonGetData_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```